# Code doesn't seem to work for larger inputs, but works fine for smaller inputs

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

While solving [this question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/birthday-cake-candles/), my code doesn't seem to work for larger inputs like 100000, but seems to work fine for smaller inputs.

Here's the code:

```
int main() {
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */ 
long long int n, h;
cin>>n;
long long int count=0;
long long int i,j;
long long int arr[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>arr[i];
    //cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}
h = arr[0];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if (arr[i]>=h)
    {
        h=arr[i];
        for(j=i;j<n;j++)
        { if (arr[j]<h)
                count++;
        }       


    }
}
cout<<(n-count);
//cout<<h;    
return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: That is not actually C++, because you ignore the great standard library containers that would spare you these problems, and use a non-standard extension of VLAs instead.

Comment: Understood, sorry I'm a beginner, so don't have much experience. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, VLAs (`arr[n]`) are non-standard in C++. Secondly, where they are supported (e.g. as language extensions in g++), they are typically stored on the stack, which has a finite size, and so you are most likely encountering a... **stack overflow**. Solution: use a proper C++ container (e.g. `std::vector`) instead of a VLA, e.g. change:

```
long long int arr[n];
```

to:

```
std::vector<long long int> arr(n);
```

(and don't forget to `#include <vector>`).